# Can't bind tablenames and columns names with PDO. 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

So I am new to php and have gone through phpacademys OOP registration system tutorials. I am having trouble completing the following query.

```
/**
 * Get an array of listings (all or by category)
 * @param null $category
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getListings($category = null) {
    if(!$category) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ? WHERE ? = ?";
        $this->_db->query($sql, ['listings', 'active', 1]);
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ? WHERE ? = ? AND ? = ?;";
        $this->_db->query($sql, ['listings', 'active', 1, 'category', $category]);
    }

        return $this->_db->results();
}
```

This is my query method in the database class

```
    /**
 * Perform a query
 * @param $sql
 * @param array $params
 * @return $this
 */
public function query($sql, $params = array()){
    $this->_error = false;
    echo $sql;
    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)){
        $x = 1;
        if(count($params)){
            foreach($params as $param){
                    $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                    $x++;
            }
        }
        if($this->_query->execute()){
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        }else{
            $this->_error = true;
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Here is an error on the page I'm calling the getListings function on:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''listings' WHERE 'active' = '1' AND 'category' = 'computers'' at line 1' in /var/www/html/classes/DB.php:57 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/classes/DB.php(57): PDOStatement->execute() #1 /var/www/html/classes/Listing.php(161): DB->query('SELECT * FROM ?...', Array) #2 /var/www/html/browse.php(14): Listing->getListings('computers') #3 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/classes/DB.php on line 57
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't bind (replaced by parameters) tablenames and columns in your PDO query.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ? WHERE ? = ?";
        $this->_db->query($sql, ['listings', 'active', 1]);
```

Must by:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM listings WHERE active = ?";
        $this->_db->query($sql, [1]);
```

And:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ? WHERE ? = ? AND ? = ?;";
    $this->_db->query($sql, ['listings', 'active', 1, 'category', $category]);
```

Must by:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM listings WHERE active = ? AND category = ?;";
    $this->_db->query($sql, [1, $category]);
```

Read more at:

> https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php#69304